# Docker containers as Build Agents has error "filesystem operations against a running Hyper-V container are not supported"

Tags: docker, jenkins

On Windows 10 (1903), I'm running Jenkins in a Linux container.  I'm trying to use the Docker Plugin to spin up Docker Agents, but it keeps getting a "filesystem operations against a running Hyper-V container are not supported" error.  I believe this error means that files are trying to be copied to a container. Does anyone know what I doing wrong or missing?

---

For testing I trimmed my Docker Agent image to just:

```
FROM centos:latest
```

---

The Jenkins log:

```
Finished DockerContainerWatchdog Asynchronous Periodic Work. 18 ms
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud provision
Asked to provision 1 slave(s) for: testslave
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud canAddProvisionedSlave
Provisioning 'jenkins-slave' on 'LocalDockerHost'; Total containers: 0 (of 100)
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud provision
Will provision 'jenkins-slave', for label: 'testslave', in cloud: 'LocalDockerHost'
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$StandardStrategyImpl apply
Started provisioning Image of jenkins-slave from LocalDockerHost with 1 executors. Remaining excess workload: 0
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate doProvisionNode
Trying to run container for jenkins-slave
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate doProvisionNode
Trying to run container for node docker-00001yrz9aglv from image: jenkins-slave
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:07 PM INFO com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate doProvisionNode
Started container ID 39db6b07f16e98ea37844fcc54e18a8d95a1f29a8cc0386bcb5a2c672d912daa for node docker-00001yrz9aglv from image: jenkins-slave
Aug 19, 2019 4:04:08 PM SEVERE com.github.dockerjava.core.async.ResultCallbackTemplate onError
Error during callback
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: {"message":"filesystem operations against a running Hyper-V container are not supported"}

    at com.github.dockerjava.netty.handler.HttpResponseHandler.channelRead0(HttpResponseHandler.java:109)
    at com.github.dockerjava.netty.handler.HttpResponseHandler.channelRead0(HttpResponseHandler.java:33)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

so the odds are you need to turn on virtualization in your local machines bios settings. 
This will require you to reboot your machine find the setting and turn it on.